# C++ calling a vector of classes' method in another class

Tags: c++

```
class C {
  public: void c_set(int x){ a = x; }
  private: int a;
}
;
 class U {
  public: void load();
         c_loader(int i, int x){ c[i].c_set(x); };
  private: vector<C> c(20);
}
;
 void U::load() {
  int x;
  cin >> x >> i;
  c_loader(i, x)
}
```

I'm really confused with this one. I need to call a member function in another one but my problem is that the inside class is a vector of that classes. My code is supposed to work but the result is segfault. Presume that the function `cget` has definition.

Comment: The last line a suppose to be x.

Comment: Is load supposed to be a method of U?

Comment: `load()` may be declared inline (i.e. inside the class) like `public: void load() { ... }` or you have to prepend the class name to the function name like `void U::load() { ... }`. `x` is not initialised. And finally `c` is empty (which leads to a segfault when you try to access its members).

Comment: @James - first edit the code as others have mentioned. What is the initial value of x? You need to add some C instances to the vector before accessing it.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the above code. The last line must be defined as class U method as a function that has an two arguments ; an index(because I want to have access to all the vectors' elements) and the value is going to be kept. Another point is that with this process I want to change value of one of class C fields

Comment: @James And welcome to Stackoverflow BTW. ;-)

Comment: and try to put code that compiles otherwise you will have loads of comments on bugs in your code that are not related to your actual question

Comment: Presume that my answer is below

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear but try this to prevent segfault.

```
class C {
  public: void cget(int a);
  private: int a;
};

class U {
  public: void load();

  vector<C> c;    // Note: c is made public in order to add elements from main
};

 void U::load(unsigned x, int a) {
  if (x < c.size())   // Check the size of c _before_ access
  {
    c[x].cget(a);
  }
}

void main()
{
  U u;
  C c;
  u.c.push_back(c);
  u.load(0, 3);  // Will end up calling cget
  u.load(1, 3);  // Will just return without calling cget
}
```

EDIT:
Just want to mention that the code in the question has changed a lot sinse my answer. That explains why my code looks quite different ;-)
In any case, the answer is still: Check the size of c before accessing it.

Comment: I think I found  where the problem was. The reason of segfault was that I didn't initialized the vector in this block. Sorry about the problems in code. ;-)